# how to get o/p as {"Chennai": ["Ram", "stephen"], "Mumbai": "Laxman"} for given i/p = {"Ram": "Chennai", "Laxman": "Mumbai", "stephen": "Chennai"}

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to use defaultdict function here but that does not seem to work

```
s = {"Ram": "Chennai", "Laxman": "Mumbai", "stephen": "Chennai"} 
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
sorted(d.items())
print(d)
```

Comment: `for k, v in s.items()` and `d[v].append(k)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict


s = {"Ram": "Chennai", "Laxman": "Mumbai", "stephen": "Chennai"} 
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s.items():
    d[v].append(k)

sorted(d.items())
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Chennai': ['Ram', 'stephen'], 'Mumbai': ['Laxman']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over keys and values simultaneously so you have to use `s.items()` to get both key-value pairs as tuples: `[('Ram', 'Chennai'), ('Laxman', 'Mumbai'), ('stephen', 'Chennai')]`

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = {"Ram": "Chennai", "Laxman": "Mumbai", "stephen": "Chennai"} 
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s.items():
    d[v].append(k) # Append k instead of v
sorted(d.items())
print(d) # {'Chennai': ['Ram', 'stephen'], 'Mumbai': ['Laxman']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were iterating through `key` and `val` of a `dict` without a call to `items()`, also the new `dict` should have `keys` with city name hence had to interchange in `v` and `k` in the `for` loop. Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = {"Ram": "Chennai", "Laxman": "Mumbai", "stephen": "Chennai"} 
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s.items():
    d[v].append(k)
sorted(d.items())
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Chennai': ['Ram', 'stephen'], 'Mumbai': ['Laxman']})
```